# List isn't outputting correctly

Tags: c#, list, class, member

I have a list which I am reading data into. I checked how to output a list but what is working for others isn't working for me.  I noticed none of the examples I seen every used a class in a list tho like I am, and I can't find an example like that.

Here's my code:

```
private static void AddCar(Vechicle _Motor, List<Vechicle> vehicles)
      {
          //int number = 1;
          Console.Clear();

          Vechicle v = new Vechicle();
          Console.Write("/////////////////////ADDING CAR DETAILS\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
          Console.Write("\n\nEnter Make: ");
          v.Make = Console.ReadLine();              
          Console.Write("\n\nEnter Model: ");
          v.Model = Console.ReadLine();              
          Console.Write("\n\nEnter Year: ");
          v.Year = Console.ReadLine();
          vehicles.Add(v);
          Console.Clear();
         foreach (Vechicle value in vehicles)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(vehicles);
          }


      }
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Thanks for any help!

I now changed:

```
foreach (Vechicle value in vehicles)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(vehicles);
          }
```

TO:

```
foreach (Vechicle value in vehicles)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(value);
          }
```

as suggested in the comments but now I get this:

[image: result]

Comment: It looks like there's also a typo. `Console.WriteLine(vehicles)` should be `Console.WriteLine(value)`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I want the output that is read into make, model & year ( which is then read into the list) to be the output. Any chance of a link to that duplicate? 

nope, that never worked. All other examples I seen had the variable after the 'in', in the parameters.

Comment: The examples were wrong then. @p.s.w.g is correct.

Comment: ...no, it should be `Console.WriteLine(value)`.  Here is the reference for foreach in C#:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: Ahh, another typo apparently, you named your variable `vaule` not `value`.

Comment: Tried to find good duplicate and failed... surprisingly search for list and toString give way too many unrelated issues... posted as answer instead.

Comment: @p.s.w.g noticed that second typo after your first suggestion, I'm while for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overload the ToString method in your vehicle class or make a method that returns a string of the make model and year.

Some Example Code.

```
    public class Vehicles
    {
        public string Make;
        public string Model;
        public string Year;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Make + " " + Model + " " + Year;
        }
    }
```

With the ToString method overridden whenever you call Vehicles.ToString() it will return make model year.

Answer (score 6):

By default `Console.WriteLine` will call `ToString` on argument you passed is - since you are passing collection it uses default implementation of `ToString` which simply prints class name.

If `Vehicle` overrides `.ToString` with some reasonable output ([see other answer for implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26621551/477420) ) than simply pass `value` to `Console.WriteLine`:

```
 foreach (var value in vehicles)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(value);
 }
```

Or print whatever you need directly:

```
    foreach (var value in vehicles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Make: {0}, model:{1}", value.Make, value.Model);
    }
```

---

For `.ToString()` consider using `String.Format` as it will give more formatting options than `+` if you want something with fixed withd or non-default number formats:

```
 public class Vehicles
 { 
    ....
    public override string ToString() 
    { 
       return String.Format("Make: {0}, model:{1}", Make, Model);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes you suggested but I was still getting the wrong output. It then used your suggestion along with the other answer and it worked.

Comment: @deathismyfriend "You need either pass "(if Vehicle overrides .ToString with some reasonable output:" this is probably what you said in your post, but I couldn't make sense of it in this form.

Comment: @COYG I didn't even notice that statement. I was only referring to the foreach (var value in vehicles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    } Because you were using vehicles in place of values.

Comment: @COYG - yes... the sentence was somewhat awkward :) reworded so probably more readable.